# Не работает редирект при отправке формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Не происходит редирект при отправке формы. Подскажите пожалуйста, где я допустил ошибку?

```js
var formData = JSON.stringify($("#signUpForm").serializeArray());

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  data: "form",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
});

var redirect = function(url, method) {
  $("signUpForm", {
    method: method,
    action: url
  }).submit();
  redirect("http:\\companies.html", "POST");
};

var secondTry = function(json) {
  if ($("#signUpForm").valid) {
    window.location.href = "http:\\companies.html";
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" class="sign-form" id="signUpForm">
  <label class="sign-form__input-container">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First Name" required class="sign-form__input-field">
   </label>
  <label class="sign-form__input-container">
    <input type="text" name="secondname" placeholder="Last Name" required class="sign-form__input-field">
   </label>

  <input type="submit" value="send" class="sign-form__send-button">
</form>
```

Comment: "где я допустил ошибку" - желательно сначала объяснить словами, что Вы хотели сделать

Comment: @Igor нужно, чтобы при отправке формы происходил редирект на другую страницу

Answer (score 1):

`redirect` - неправильное название для этого действия.

```
var submitForm = function(url, method) {
  $("#signUpForm", { // # was missing in the selector
    method: method,
    action: url
  }).submit();
};
submitForm("http://domain?/companies.html", "POST");

var secondTry = function() {
  if ($("#signUpForm").valid) {
    window.location.href = "http://domain?/companies.html";
  }
};
secondTry();
```

Comment: Скопировал Ваш код, отправка формы происходит, а редирект - нет.
Консоль не ругается.